# How to call a JNI Java function from MASM

Tags: java-native-interface, masm

I'm writing simple program in assembler which will be called from Java by JNI.
I want to execute function from JNI, which according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) is under 187 index. While i'm performing this line:

```
call qword ptr[rax + 187*8]
```

I'm reciving access violation error. What am I possible doing wrong? (I'm multipling index by 8 because of x64 architecture).
All code which i'm performing:

```
push rdx                  ; save Java array pointer for later use
push rdi                  ; save JNIEnv pointer for later use
push rcx                  ; save array length for later use
mov rsi, rdx              ; set array parameter for GetIntArrayElements
mov rax, [rdi]            ; get location of JNI function table
xor edx, edx              ; set isCopy parameter to false for GetIntArrayElements
call qword ptr[rax + 187*8]
```

Comment: Your use of MASM implies to me that you're on Windows. But your code is written as if the System V 64-bit ABI is used, rather than the Windows 64-bit ABI. Are you sure that that's correct (i.e. have you looked at the contents of the registers in a debugger)? On 64-bit Windows, the first four arguments would normally be passed in `RCX`, `RDX`, `R8` and `R9`.

Comment: @Michael You might be right. I blindly follwed a tutorial on some webpage. Please tell me where I can look from information how to pass data to JNI functions.

Comment: I mean for example from which register the call qword ptr[rax + 187*8] will take the arguments? Where I can find all this informations

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention

Comment: I've already read that. I was wondering if there is a .. greater article. There is still no information from where call takes arguments to perform function. Anyway thanks a lot!

Comment: _"There is still no information from where call takes arguments to perform function"_. Sure there is: **It uses registers RCX, RDX, R8, R9 for the first four integer or pointer arguments (in that order)**